# Weird behaviour of windows in 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gui

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and in the last two days it became almost unusable... As an example, the menu of the terminal is not responsible and Nautilus works only if the terminal is not running. Do you have tips on how to fix this?

Comment: did you do any particular edit inside GUI or terminal parameters?

Comment: Do you remember making any *unusual* change to your system (e.g. installing an application/package, making any change in configuration, running any *non-trivial* command etc.) before these started to happen?

Comment: @damadam not that I can think of

Comment: @pomsky No. I just updated the system. Also, I tried to fix the issue reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all` but that didn't work.

Comment: This may sound silly but, have you tried restarting the machine? I had a similar thing happen last week and two reboots fixed it. It was after an update for my nvidia card.

Comment: I rebooted a dozen times at least. I hoped that would fix the issue but nope

Comment: What was the update? Can you check the update logs and then try to uninstall / reinstall those specific updates?